# Context bounds and pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala

I am experimenting with context bounds in scala and I don't find a way to make the either of these two functions typecheck:

```
abstract class Expr
case class Val[T: Numeric](v: T) extends Expr
case object Other extends Expr

val e1 = Val(1)
val e2 = Val(2)

def addExp1(e1: Expr, e2: Expr): Expr = (e1, e2) match {
  case (Val(v1), Val(v2)) => Val(v1+v2)
  case _ => Other
}

def addExp2[T: Numeric](e1: Expr, e2: Expr): Expr = (e1, e2) match {
  case (Val(v1: T), Val(v2: T)) => Val(v1+v2)
  case _ => Other
}
```

In the case of addExp1, I can understand that the compiler has no information at the function definition point to know that the arguments of Val are Numeric and thus have a + method. It just matches Any as the type of v1.

In the case of addExp2, how can I force the bound in the pattern? The type is "erased"...T annotation is eliminated by erasure...

What I would dream of having is a single point to put the bound, ideally at the definition of the Val class.

Comment: Do you only get a warning or do you get an error in `addExp2`? I'm having to do `Val(implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(v1, v2))` instead of `Val(v1+v2)` to get it to compile without errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you pattern match, the two instances of `Val` can have different type parameters, say `Val[T1]` and `Val[T2]`.

You can fix that as suggested by @rjsvaljean, and add `import Numeric.Implicits._` to use the nice operator notation.

Answer (score 3):

One way to avoid losing the parameterised type of Val is to have Expr take a type parameter as well.

```
abstract class Expr[T]
case class Val[T: Numeric](v: T) extends Expr[T]
case object Other extends Expr[Nothing]

val e1 = Val(1)
val e2 = Val(2)



def addExp2[T: Numeric](e1: Expr[T], e2: Expr[T]): Expr[_ <: T] = (e1, e2) match {
  case (Val(v1), Val(v2)) => Val(implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(v1, v2))
  case _ => Other
}


addExp2[Int](e1, e2)
```

This compiles with no warnings.

Now all we need is a way to specify a default type of `Nothing` for the type parameter of Expr :).

Comment: You actually still have warnings with the version you posted: `warning: abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`. Tested with scala 2.10. You need to change `Val(v1: T)` into just `Val(v1)`

Comment: Indeed. My mistake. Copied in the non-final version.

Comment: Thanks. My actual problem is more complicated and I will not use Numeric after all by your answer has improved my understanding of these concepts.